# Visual Studio 2019 Bookmarks disappearing

Tags: visual-studio, bookmarks

So I have this issue for quite a while now, but I cant figure out the cause nor when it happens.
It seems that, after I create my bookmarks in Visual Studio 2019, they spontaneously disappear without any pattern. I first thought the enable/disable checkboxes were responsible for that so I just had all bookmarks enabled. But somehow they disappear even when I dont make any changes to the code.
That bookmarks disappear when I make changes to the corresponding line is expectable. But why do they vanish without me doing anythihng (that I can recall would lead to something like that)? Its really frustrating because I need a lot of those bookmarks.

I found [this](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39836/bookmarks-are-lost-after-running-program-vs2017-an.html) issue on Microsofts website but they didnt seem to find a solution, mainly because there were too few information.

Anyone else can relate to this or help me out? Im definitely not deleting them. What could be the cause? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the disappearing bookmarks is triggered by right click/"Rename..." on an identifier. The rename takes place but bookmarks and breakpoints disappear. This is on VS 16.6.2. It's a real productivity killer.

Comment: It doesn't happen 100% of the time, though.

Comment: yeah same here its very weird and even after a search online there was only one issue from microsoft which was closed because of too few information

Comment: Year 2023, VS 17.5 this still happens!